# Problem with caret position when modifying a field (HTML+JS)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, regex, forms

The original developer programmed the following JavaScript, which is a little amateurish in my opinion, but I don't work much in Javscript, so I can't offer a better solution with the time I have.

The problem I do need to solve is that each time you press any key that sends input to the text field (any `<input type="text" class="phone_val"...`), the caret moves to the end, cause the code is replacing it.

The purpose of the code is to format the number for use in the database.  Allowed patterns are:

```
          235 - 5555
    (321) 234 - 5555
  1 (321) 234 - 5555
 21 (321) 234 - 5555
012 (321) 234 - 5555
```

These are the phone number types we use in our customer base.  I need to be able to apply these patterns without the caret (text cursor position) moving to the end every time a key is pressed.  It's not a problem until the person needs to correct some characters in the middle of the field.  I wouldn't mind being able to seriously simplify and shrink the code down as well, with a regular expression.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="phone_val" style="width: 85%; text-align: right;"
       value="<%= CustomerFields("billing_phone") %>" id="billing_phone"
       name="billing_phone" tabindex="10" />
```

Javascript (jQuery assumed):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.phone_val').attr('maxlength', 20);
    $('.phone_val').keyup(function(){
        var startVal, finVal, i;
        startVal = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g,'');
        if (startVal.length <= 7) {
            finVal = "";
            for (i = 0; i < startVal.length; i += 1) {
                if (i === 3) {
                    finVal += " - " + startVal.charAt(i);
                }
                else {
                    finVal += startVal.charAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (startVal.length > 7 && startVal.length < 11) {
            finVal = "(";
            for (i = 0; i < startVal.length; i += 1) {
                if (i === 3) {
                    finVal += ") " + startVal.charAt(i);
                }
                else if (i === 6) {
                    finVal += " - " + startVal.charAt(i);
                }
                else {
                    finVal += startVal.charAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (startVal.length >= 11) {
            finVal = "";
            stopP = startVal.length < 13 ? startVal.length - 11 : 2;
            for (i = 0; i < startVal.length; i += 1) {
                if (i === stopP) {
                    finVal += startVal.charAt(i) + " (";
                }
                else if (i === (stopP + 4)) {
                    finVal += ") " + startVal.charAt(i);
                }
                else if (i === (stopP + 7)) {
                    finVal += " - " + startVal.charAt(i);
                }
                else {
                    finVal += startVal.charAt(i);
                }
            }
        }

        if (startVal.length < 4) {
            finVal = finVal.replace(/\D/g,'');
        }
        $(this).val(finVal);
    });
});
```

Comment: I was thinking about having the code wait a couple of seconds after the user stops typing before applying the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is horrible on many levels. For the user, there are two bad things here: first, changing input as you type is confusing and annoying, and second, moving the caret to the end every time you type a character is just infuriating. While it is possible to write code to move the caret, I'd recommend against it and instead suggest doing the validation in the `change` or `blur` events, or waiting for a period of a few seconds of keyboard inactivity as you suggest in your comment.

Comment: These were my thoughts exactly.  I'm against formatting phone numbers and email addresses as it is, but the boss claims it's important to the techs' management.  So, I like the idea of waiting a period or doing onBlur, however I've been having difficulty with the regular expressions-- first I have to remove all letters, then I have to replace different numbers of letters with different formats. Removing everything but digits is easy... `startVal.replace(/\D/g, '')`.  But now should I nest .replace() calls? Or is there one regex that will take care of it all?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've got so far:

```
$('.phone_val').blur(function () {
    var inpVal = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g, ''); //get rid of everything but numbers

    // RegEx for:
    //    xxx (xxx) xxx - xxxx
    //     xx (xxx) xxx - xxxx
    //      x (xxx) xxx - xxxx
    //        (xxx) xxx - xxxx
    inpVal = inpVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/, '$1($2) $3 - $4');

    // RegEx for (needs a separate one because of the parentheses):
    //              xxx - xxxx
    inpVal = inpVal.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{4})$/, '$1 - $2');

    $(this).val(inpVal);
});
```

That takes care of 7 digits and 10-13 digits, but I'm not sure what to do with the ones in between. Should I format those as well, so that the user can see their mistakes easily? Or should I leave them alone?